# Is there a program/game i can build a deck and play against AI's without a net connection?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

When i build my deck i like to try and test it out to see what flaws could be exploited and cards used to exploit those flaws while also seeing how difficult it is to implement my strategies while also learning of new cards i may want to get in order to strength my deck.

problem is that the i can't test it out how i want to, i'm not privilege enough to have many players (if at all) to help test my deck in my area and if i go into the city players tend to reserve their opinion, assuming that it's because they don't want me patching up my deck to potentially defeat them in a rematch.

I use a program called YVD (Yu-Gi-Oh Virtual Desktop) which is normally up to date with every card currently released and allows me to duel players however random duels with human players tend to be nonconstructive as when i loose my opponent doesn't stick around for me to learn where i went wrong and while i could rig a couple of machines to connect locally and duel an identical deck this fails in me learning of new cards or strategies which could be used against me.

Now i am looking for a program/game similar to YVD however has a single player aspect for dueling AI players, while pale in comparison to human players who can come up with strategies and see and exploit flaws in my deck, an AI can help me prepare a better deck.

the things YVD has which i also want

- Complete database of cards (or can be updated)
- Allowing both tournament and non-tournament decks (my non-tournament tend to have tournament banned cards like Change of Heart and tends to get close to 100 cards)
- Preferable free to download but i am willing to pay for it however to get cards that has to be free, i dont want to be spending money getting digital versions of my cards just as a test before i go off to buy them physically
- Has AI Players or a single AI Player which is assigned decks meaning i can recreate decks posted on forums/wikis and duel against them as a test
- Can be played Offline without ever needing to connect to the internet (not even for installing), this is because my main computer doesn't connect to the net and my laptop which does is getting on in the years and tends to burn up during summer

Platform must either be Windows, iOS or Android, while i can accept consoles most console Yu-Gi-Oh games on consoles start you off with a starter deck and it takes forever for you to get all the cards needed to mimic a deck you have created in real life

Comment: This probably doesn't exist. [MtG has](http://mtgrares.blogspot.com/2010/05/forges-awesome-ai.html?m=1) a fan made AI, but the designer notes some of its flaws. Most video game AI for this sort of games have a very limited number of cards in their decks, and have custom tuned responses for the cards it knows it has in its deck. You want some sort of generic AI that can play any card, and play that card properly in any deck. You want some sort of human level intelligence that no one is capable of (especially for free).

Comment: @user1873 i'd like to point out, the AI you posted a link to is for Magic the Gathering, not Yu-Gi-Oh (Duel Monsters) and i can't read there of anything that says it would be compatible with Duel Monster's Rules

Comment: @user1873 i also said "Has AI Players **or** a single AI Player which is assigned decks" while i would prefer the second one the first one would be ok, the main point was i didn't want a single AI with a single deck

Comment: @user1873 "Preferable free to download but to get cards that has to be free" i thought this explained itself however i'll edit the question to make it clearer, the program/game i would rather get for free if i had to pay for it i will (after i evaluate it) however the cards have to be gotten for free as i said it's be a waste of money to buy the digital cards just for experiments to build a physical deck

Comment: Nice try, SkyNet.  We will not help you become self-aware!

Comment: @Memor-X Yes, it's a Magic AI - user1873 said it was. The point was to demonstrate the kinds of limitations these things usually have, by way of explaining that you probably won't find what you're looking for. The other details you're discussing don't really change that. The problem is just that it's difficult to impossible to build an AI that can play with arbitrary decks, whether or not it plays as one player or multiple, and whether or not the resulting software costs money.

Answer (score 4):

Try YGOPRO it actually works and does everything you need. It even has an offline AI.

Comment: YGOPRO does not let you use the cards you already have in real life you have to purchase card packs or win by playing with generic cards pre-given by the game. On top of that some cards you cant get from card packs you have to have 2 or more of a certain cards go create certain cards in the game.

Comment: Not sure what the guy above me is talking about.  YGOPro is free, and you don't need to pay for cards.  He may be confusing it with some other program, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing.

The best you might get is random opponents via Internet. Or outdated programs with a programmend AI. But if you want to stay up to date, there is no other option than playing actual opponents.

If you decide to go for random opponents, Dueling Network and DevPro are the most well-known online sites that offer playing Yu-gi-Oh!, DevPro being somewhat better due to a Rules Engine (Dueling Network is basically a virtual playing table like YVD) taking care of rules stuff for you. Seeing as they can do that, it might be realistic to find an AI on there someday, but it won't come as an offline version.